# Chi square test with different sample sizes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have two sets of data as shown below. Each data set have a different length

`X_data1` and `Y_data1` (black binned data) have a length of 40 whereas `X_data2` and `Y_data2` (red) have a length of 18k.

I would like to perform a Chi-Square Goodness of Fit Test on these two data as follows

```
from scipy import stats
stats.chisquare(f_obs=Y_data1, f_exp=Y_data2)
```

But I can not since the vector size is not the same and I receive an error.

> ~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py in chisquare(f_obs, f_exp, ddof, axis)    6850     6851     """
> -> 6852     return power_divergence(f_obs, f_exp=f_exp, ddof=ddof, axis=axis,    6853                             lambda_="pearson")
> 6854
>
> ~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py in
> power_divergence(f_obs, f_exp, ddof, axis, lambda_)    6676     if
> f_exp is not None:    6677         f_exp = np.asanyarray(f_exp)
> -> 6678         bshape = _broadcast_shapes(f_obs_float.shape, f_exp.shape)    6679         f_obs_float =
> _m_broadcast_to(f_obs_float, bshape)    6680         f_exp = _m_broadcast_to(f_exp, bshape)
>
> ~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py in
> _broadcast_shapes(shape1, shape2)
> 184             n = n1
> 185         else:
> --> 186             raise ValueError(f'shapes {shape1} and {shape2} could not be '
> 187                              'broadcast together')
> 188         shape.append(n)
>
> ValueError: shapes (40,) and (18200,) could not be broadcast together

Is there a way in Python that I can compare these two data?

[image]

Comment: What is the error message you're getting? What line of code is it referencing to?

Comment: I have edited my question and added the whole error message. the short message would be: ValueError: shapes (40,) and (18200,) could not be broadcast together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this unless both `f_exp` and `f_obs` have the same length. You can achieve your goal by interpolating `Y_data2` on the x-axis of `Y_data1`. You can do it as follows:

```python
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline 
spl = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(X_data2, Y_data2)
new_Y_data2 = spl(X_data1)
```

As both `Y_data1` and `new_Y_data2` have same lengths now, you can use them in `stats.chisquare` as follows:

```python
from scipy import stats
stats.chisquare(f_obs=Y_data1, f_exp=new_Y_data2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please elaborate a bit on what exactly interpolating does to my data2 to match data 1? Does it take an average value of data2 around each point of data1?

Comment: It gives you the value of data2 for the x points on data1 by using 1D spline interpolation, which means that you get for x-axis the points for data2. As you already have data1 (which has the same x-axis that is used for interpolation of data2), the comparison makes sense. This actually is not an average. You can understand it better by seeing [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html).